# Custom Animation in Fragment Transaction not working

Tags: android, animation, fragment

```
MFragment fragment = new MFragment();
final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,
        R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left,
        R.anim.slide_out_right);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment,
        "frag1");
fragmentTransaction.commit();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MFragment fragment = new MFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left,
                R.anim.slide_out_right);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack("frag2");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}, 3000);
```

When I load the `FragmentActivity` and add the **frag1**, it is **added with proper animation, sliding in from right to left**.

But the 2nd fragment **frag2** which is supposed to replace **frag1**, **comes up with fade in/out animation, the default one**. And when I press back button **frag2 pops out with fade animation instead of sliding out from left to right**.

**anim/slide_in_right.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```